# Generate or Specify Azure Service Bus Namespace SAS Token with ARM Template

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure ARM templates in order to make sure that I can repeatedly deploy uniform infrastructure and services. My ARM template consists of an App Service, Web App, Service Bus Queue, and Azure SQL database. On top of this, I'm setting up continuous deployment through VSTS.

Everything is working well EXCEPT I am not sure how to set a Service Bus SAS token at the Namespace level. I don't see a way in the Service Bus ARM template to specify one, so I cannot pre-generate a token and place it in my web.config file. I also don't see a way to have one generated on my behalf, then pull the values back to my web.config file. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if `listkeys` method can do that, probably not, but at the very worst you can use powershell to retrieve that token after the template was deployed and push that to the WebApp

Comment: @4c74356b41, I have taken the Azure Powershell approach to create and retrieve the token. However, I am not sure how I can pass that to future tasks in the VSTS Build process. Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have two options:

1) Get generated key from the output:

```
"outputs": {
        "eh:Endpoint": {
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/authorizationRules', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'), 'SendOnlyKey'),'2015-08-01').primaryKey]",
            "type": "string"
        },
    }
```

And incorporate it in your build/release process.

2) Try to push a key with a template:

```
{
            "apiVersion": "[parameters('eventHubVersion')]",
            "name": "[variables('eventHubNamespaceName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
                    "name": "[variables('eventHubName')]",
                    "type": "eventHubs",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "path": "[variables('eventHubName')]",
                        "MessageRetentionInDays": "[parameters('messageRetentionInDays')]",
                        "PartitionCount": "[parameters('partitionCount')]"
                    },
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "[parameters('eventHubVersion')]",
                            "name": "StorageRetention",
                            "type": "consumergroups",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[variables('eventHubName')]",
                                "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'))]"
                            ],
                            "tags": {
                                "displayName": "eh"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "[parameters('eventHubVersion')]",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'),'/SendOnlyKey')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/authorizationRules",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "properties": {
                        "KeyName": "SendOnlyKey",
                        "ClaimType": "SendSharedAccessKey",
                        "ClaimValue": "None",
                        "PrimaryKey": "[parameters('eventHubSendPrimaryKey')]",
                        "SecondaryKey": "your_key",
                        "Rights": [ "Send" ],
                        "Revision": -1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "[parameters('eventHubVersion')]",
                    "name": "[concat(variables('eventHubNamespaceName'),'/ListenOnlyKey')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/authorizationRules",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/', variables('eventHubNamespaceName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "properties": {
                        "KeyName": "ListenOnlyKey",
                        "ClaimType": "ReceiveSharedAccessKey",
                        "ClaimValue": "None",
                        "PrimaryKey": "your_key",
                        "SecondaryKey": "your_key",
                        "Rights": [ "Listen" ],
                        "Revision": -1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

However note that the second solutions works only for an older version of API and sooner or later will be deprecated. Additionally I tested it only for pushing keys for a hub, not a namespace.

Comment: Thank you, Kamo! I will try both of your suggestions as soon as I get into the office. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The first approach using ListKeys was the way to go. I've got it working in my template now. Thanks!

Comment: Is there documenation on the the second approach being deprecated?

Comment: @bearrito Take into consideration the version used `2014-09-01` - I don't think that there's any official statement, I talked to someone from support and he passed a communication from people responsible for ARM API. Since exposing a key was considered a bad practice, they agreed on deprecating this version of API.

Comment: Agreed. I am adding an answer that might be of assistance to future searchers.

Answer (score 1):

This might help others arriving at this answer

In EastUS using API_VERSION = 2017-04-01

The following will work to obtain references to primarykey and related fields

```
  - connectionString: "[concat('',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs/authorizationRules','{{ eh_namespace }}', '{{ eventhub_name }}','fw'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString,'')]"
```